# For how long is imgur supposed to store images used on this site?

Tags: discussion

We've been telling people to put images using the included tool which hosts them on imgur and that they're supposed to be hosted there and safe from removal by the host.

I've seen that it isn't so, but I didn't at the time I didn't save links to particular questions and answers. Now I found [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/4803/1240) question of mine which, at least for me, has a missing picture and the direct link times out.

I've got the impression that the images uploaded to imgur should be saved for considerable time in order to be useful for some time after the question has been made. So what I want to know is how long that time is?

Comment: Also should I have asked this on SO meta? I think that it affects the whole network, but I can't provide links that prove that right now.

Comment: No, here is fine.  All metas are monitored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Images uploaded through the image uploader in the editor are uploaded into Stack Exchange's imgur account.  Images on this account should never* disappear.  Should anything happen, there are a couple processes we've got going on that would allow us to correct for something serious happening.

The image loads fine for me on your question.  Network blip perhaps?

*For as long as imgur exists, of course.

Comment: That's the idea I've got, but the [direct link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bjUUt.jpg) to the picture is still down. This isn't the first time I've seen something like this. I'll continue monitoring the situation and see if it somehow solves itself.

Comment: Yeah, that's loading just fine for me.  Is it 1) that image only, 2) any i.stack image, or 3) anything from imgur?

Comment: Looks like it's down just for me. The rest of images work fine though.

Comment: Looks like it's imgur's problem. Take a look [here](http://imgur.userecho.com/topic/55333-i-cant-see-many-of-my-uploaded-images/)and [here](http://imgur.userecho.com/topic/55341-images-not-loading-even-after-dns-change/). Let's hope they fix it soon.